# Instantiate prefab around a object

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a scene with a body maked with makehuman, and I need to add a simple prefab (a torus) around the arm of the body when the user touch the arm.

I tried:

1. `Instantiate` the prefab in the point where the user touch, but the prefab apear in the *border* of the arm.
2. `Instantiate` the prefab in the center of the arm, with this code:

```
    float radio = hit.transform.collider.radius; // the arm has a capsuleCollider
    Ray r = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0));
    Vector3 origin = r.origin;
    float distance = (origin - hit.point).magnitude;
    RaycastHit ou;
    Vector3 position = hit.point;
    Ray r2 = new Ray(r.GetPoint(distance + 10f), -r.direction);
    if (cc.Raycast(r2, out ou, distance + 10f))
         position = (hit.point + ou.point) / 2;

    Instantiate(Prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

This try to  Select the center of the arm and initialite a torus.

The second option works in some cases, but the general impression is that is the wrong way to do it.

How can I add a prefab around a collider? or, how can I modify the mesh to add a visual indicator?

Answer (score 1):

This should work a lot better as well as look a lot cleaner:

```
Vector3 center = hit.transform.collider.bounds.center;
Instantiate(Prefab, center, Quaternion.identity);
```

hit.transform.collider is a vital part of this process and you got that part.  collider.bounds is the bounding box that surrounds the collider (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html), and bounds.center is the center of the bounding box (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-center.html).  The Vector3 that bounds.center returns is where you want to spawn your prefab.

From there, you should be able to rotate the prefab to the desired angle and perform any number of operations you want.

Comment: Yes, `collider.center` is a good position, but the center of the collider is in the center of the arm, and it will allways appear in the center of the arm instead of the position of the hit, I need the object appear when the user click.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question.  A variable that you are able to get out of a RaycastHit is point (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) which is the point in world space where the collision occurred.  So you could instead go:

`Instantiate(Prefab, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);`